# JavaScript function scope behavior

Tags: javascript, function, scope, expression, declaration

I faced the strange behavior of JS I can't explain, hope someone can help.
Consider the following code:

```
'use strict';

// no error
function f1(n){
    (function a(k){
        a = 5;
        console.log(a);
        if(k<n)
            a(++k);
    })(1);
}

// error!!
function f2(n){
    function a(k){
        a = 5;
        console.log(a);
        if(k<n)
            a(++k);
    };
    a(1);
}

//no error
function f3(n){
    var a = function a(k){
        a = 5;
        console.log(a);
        if(k<n)
        a(++k);
    };
    a(1);
}
```

`f2(3)` invocation produces the error on `a(++k)` line that says `number is not a function` which is expected because value of a is set to number just one line earlier.
However, `f1(3)` and `f3(3)` does not show any errors and prints the function's toString result in the console! 
I found it strange because the code is executed in strict mode and if variable `a` was not declared then the code would produce the error like `a is not defined`. So `a` is defined, and of course it's the reference to function itself, but somehow setting its value has no effect in `f1` and `f3` code!

My only guess if the function expression somehow protects the reference to itself from re-writing, but how exactly it is achieved is not quite clear...

Comment: I'm always wondering why people attempt to explain such horrid coding practices.  The real answer is don't do this - ever.  If it isn't immediately obvious how and why it works the way it does, then it's likely not an easy-to-understand or maintainable or foolproof way to code.

Comment: I wouldn't do weird stuff in actual code. But it's a good idea to play around with things you don't understand, just in case you accidentally write dodgy code in the future.

Comment: I think that I never mentioned that this code is used in production and it is not for sure. I just playing with JS scope feature to better understand how exactly it works. It's all about curiosity, not the real problems..I hope that this type of questions is allowed in SO, isn't it?)

Comment: @jfriend00 Not all questions are about great practices, and neither should they be. Some things are about knowledge, for fun, science, or sheer curiosity.

Comment: By the way - if anyone interested, here is some kind of explanation https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/issues/223

Comment: I'd suggest you preface this type of question with: "I'm playing around with scoping and trying to understand some nuances of Javascript (not code I would use in production)".  My personal goal is to only supply answers here that represent good coding practices so when I see a question like this that is full of generally bad practices without any sort of special explanation, I just don't want to go anywhere near it because I don't want to contribute to perpetuating bad practices.  With an appropriate curiousity disclaimer, the question is perceived differently.

Comment: BTW - could you name the general bad practices that the code from my post is using?

Answer (score 0):

### Using an anonymous function to preserve a global variable's value

```js
function asyncFunction(callback) {
  setTimeout(callback,200);
}

var color = 'blue';

(function(color){
asyncFunction(function() {
  console.log(`this is color :${color}`);
})
}) (color);
console.log(color);

color = 'green'
```